# Check location of a from a class called by that script PHP :s

Tags: php

If I have a class (e.g Database) can I check the location of the script that tried to instantiate this class.

An example:

I have an example dir structure like so:

```
lib
  Database.class.php
app
  action.class.php
```

and in action.class.php:

```
$db = new Database;
```

and in Database.class.php

```
function __construct(){
$name = //some code to find out that app/action.class.php just tried to instantiate me
$name = explode('/',$name);
if($name[0] = 'app') //allow script to use the class
else $this->__destruct; //dont allow other scripts not in app dir for example
}
```

I dont know if this is possible or not

Regards
Luke

UPDATE:  *It seems like this is possible but not good practice (from answers below) thank you for your time, I wont be implimenting this mainly due to @Gordons argument.*

Comment: I am curious why you want this.

Comment: I was just throwing an Idea around with a plugin system that I am writing, It was/is to limit what functions plugins can use in a class.  I just wondered if it was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the calling instance or it's location in the filesystem is a dependency in the Database class, then pass it in through the constructor. If you need find out to where the file is located, use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php) or the [magic `__FILE__` constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), e.g.

```
// action.class.php 
public function initDb()
{
    $this->db = new Database($this);
}

// Database.php
public function __construct($invoker)
{
    // reflective way to get $invokerLocation
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($invoker);
    $invokerLocation = $reflector->getFileName();
    // check location
}
```

or simply

```
// action.class.php 
public function initDb()
{
    $this->db = new Database(__FILE__);
}

// Database.php
public function __construct($invokerLocation)
{
    // check location
}
```

You do not want `debug_backtrace` to find out what called the Database constructor. Like the name implies, it is for debugging purposes. Depending on the size of the trace stack, fetching the backtrace can consume a lot of time and resources. Passing it is cleaner and faster.

In addition, if you make security of your code depend on where files are located, then you introduce a dependency on the filesystem, which is code smell to me.

Comment: Do I take it by smell you mean not a good thing to do?  You would suggest not relying on dir structure for security?  What are the reasons for this? cheers Luke

Comment: @Luke. Yes, [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) is a technical term. Tieing the security to a folder name seems odd, doesn't it? You want your application to be controlled from code, not a directory layout. Also, by creating such a coupling, you make it hard to UnitTest security.

Comment: thanks for the Code Smell reference :) cool term.  Thanks for the explanation as to why its a bad idea, cheers Luke

Comment: @Luke you could lessen the impact of the coupling by having a class that can be configured with the pathes considered secure from inside the application.

Comment: sorry for being a little slow but im not entirely sure what you mean.  Unfortunately by requiring the file name/$this to be parsed through this would not work for my system as the plugin author could parse whatever they wanted. :(  Thanks for you time though.

Answer (score 1):

If you desperately need this, then [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) but it would be easier to pass the information to the constructor using

```
$db = new Database('action.class.php');
```

but it isn't a good idea to create such dependencies in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use the [`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) constant.

If you need to full stack of script files used, some [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), [debug_backtrace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and effort could give it.

Comment: No you can't, because it'll return the filename of the executing script, not of any included files where the instance might be created

Comment: That's why I was in the process of adding the edit about backtrace.